# Interpreting the use of "お日柄もよく" on this scene

Tags: meaning

I'm talking about this scene: https://youtu.be/e7E2AQQ6lGQ?list=PLxWrrb3wgaZ0RZAgITSqwGrWBsuur1lxz&t=670

Context: A yakuza sees some delinquents beating up a guy. The street happens to be his crew's territory so he teaches them a lesson. The guy who was being beat up then tries to thank him and an awkward moment happens where the yakuza glares at the guy as if to say "I didn't do this to help you". The man then awkwardly says: いや,えっとこのたびはどうも...お日柄もよく

From what I gather, お日柄もよく is a phrase often used in weddings and other events to refer to the day in question as an auspicious or lucky day. How does that apply to this specific situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, this man was very confused, and said something that doesn't make sense just to buy time. After all, almost no one knows how to speak properly in front of a yakuza who saved them. Weather is one of the common topics when you don't know what to talk about, so perhaps he wanted to say something like いい天気ですね. But he somehow felt this was not polite enough in front of a yakuza, so he ended up saying the formal wedding cliché, お日柄も良く. (Strictly speaking, お日柄もよく doesn't mean 天気がいい, but they are s somehow similar...)

Comment: Hahaha, I see. So in his confusion, he ended up saying something like "How fortunate that you picked an auspicious day..."

Comment: @jogloran Basically anything that could be heard in a formal speech would work ("on this auspicious occasion", "It's my honor to ...")

Comment: Upon a little more research it seems like there are a lot of articles explaining that お日柄も良く doesn't actually have anything to do with the weather, which makes me think it is a somewhat common assumption among native speakers that it means something  like "The weather is nice today". I feel like that usage would make a lot more sense as a phrase used to try to break an awkward silence.

Comment: @ssuga Please don't analyze something said by a confused person too much :) This scene wouldn't look funny if お日柄もよく was simply a formal way of saying いい天気ですね.